# Python: Como armazenar a documentação(help) de uma classe numa String?

Tags: python, classes

Eu estou fazendo um explorador explorador de classes em Python. Consigo armazenar os métodos e atributos da classe com

```
 dir(obj)
```

e colocá-los num TreeView. Gostaria de exibir as referências deste quando fosse clicado. Para isso eu usaria o texto do

```
 help(obj)
```

da classe em questão. Para isso precisaria do texto armazenado numa String, e assim localizar as referências sobre este com

```
 String.find(nome_do_atributo)
```

O problema é, que quando chamo o help(obj), ele imprime o texto no outuput. Alguém sabe como fazer com que o texto do help(obj) seja armazenado numa variável, em vez de ser impresso na saída do sistema?

Answer (score 1):

Sem precisar importar nada, voce poderia usar o [atributo _*doc*_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings) da funcao ou classe

eg:

```
def foo():
    """Minha docstring epicamente epica"""
    pass


class Bar():
    """Minha documentacao 100% profissional"""
    pass

func_docstring = foo.__doc__
class_docstring = Bar.__doc__

print(func_docstring)
print(class_docstring)

# Minha docstring epicamente epica
# Minha documentacao 100% profissional
```

Answer (score 0):

desculpem a minha barbeiragem, mas ralando bastante consegui achar a solução.

Primeiro, é preciso importar o pydoc

```
import pydoc
```

No Python 3:

```
string_help = pydoc.render_doc(nome_da_classe, renderer=pydoc.plaintext)
```

E se o nome da classe vier como string:

```
string_help = pydoc.render_doc(eval("nome_da_classe"), renderer=pydoc.plaintext)
```

Cuidado: o eval tem seus riscos, pois executa qualquer coisa!!!

No Phython 2, não experimentei, mas dizem que é assim, vou passar passar de boa fé, caso não funcione, me avise.

```
 string_help = pydoc.plain(pydoc.render_doc(nome_da_classe))
```

Espero que ajudade.